# Aggregating list of tuples using equivalence of certain members in tuples (via python)

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples such as:

```
[(a, 0), (a, 2), (a, 1), (a, 1), (a, 1), (a, 1), (a, 0), (b, 0), (a, 0), (b, 0), (b, 0), (b, 0), (b, 0), (b, 0), (b, 4)]
```

I want to add together all the second elements of tuples where *the first elements are the same*. I.e., the above list would become:

```
[(a,0+2+1+1+1+1+0+0),(b,0+0+0+0+0+0+4)] = [(a,6),(b,4)]
```

What is the fastest way to accomplish this in python?

Comment: it should be `(a,6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `itertools.groupby(iterable, key=None)` and `sum(iterable[, start])` functions:

```
l = [('a', 0), ('a', 2), ('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('b', 0), ('b', 0), ('b', 0), ('b', 0), ('b', 4)]
result = [(k,sum(i[1] for i in list(v))) for k,v in itertools.groupby(sorted(l), key=lambda x: x[0])]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[('a', 6), ('b', 4)]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby